# JavaScript - Greatest common divisor - stuck in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, while-loop

I am writing a function to computer the greatest common divisor for multiple numbers and I am stuck in this infinite while loop:

```
const gcd = (...nums) => {
    let answer = Math.min.apply(null, nums);
    while (answer > 0) {
        for (let index in nums) {
            if (nums[index] % answer !== 0) {
                answer--;
                break;
            } else if (index === (nums.length-1)){
               return answer;
            }
        }
    }
}

gcd(20, 155, 30)
```

For my test case on the last line, I was able to get to 5, which is the correct answer. But it seems like once the answer gets to 5,  I am not able to get to the if nor the else if statement and I am stuck in the infinite while loop.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `for in` loop with simple `for` loop. Don't use `for in` loop for iterating over arrays.

```js
const gcd = (...nums) => {
    let answer = Math.min.apply(null, nums);
    while(answer > 0) {
        for (let index = 0; index < nums.length; index++) {
            if (nums[index] % answer !== 0) {
                answer--;
                break;
            } else if (index === (nums.length-1)){
                return answer;
            } 
        }
    }
}

console.log(gcd(20, 155, 30));
```